# What would be the best way to dynamically use dates in filter function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to find workaround for `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` function since I was not able to make it work.

I can simply use `FILTER` function but having trouble how to dynamically get dates from the beginning of last year till today year back.

```
PrevYearPremium = CALCULATE(
                [Total Premium],FILTER(dim_Date,dim_Date[Date] >= VALUE("2018-01-01")
                && dim_Date[Date] <=VALUE("2018-04-18"))
                )
```

There are numerous functions like  `DATESBETWEEN`, `DATESINPERIOD`, `DATE`. What would be the best way to dynamically use dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.. This will give you YOY compare..

```
CALCULATE([Total Premium]
                        ,DATESBETWEEN('Dim_Date'[Date]
                                    ,FIRSTDATE('Dim_Date'[Date])
                                    ,LASTDATE('Dim_Date'[Date]))
                        ,DATEADD('Dim_Date'[Date],-1,YEAR)
```